# Почему не удаётся отправить почту по smtp из docker-контейнера?

Tags: laravel, docker, smtp

Пытаюсь стандартными средствами Laravel 5.4 (то есть, при помощи последней стабильной версии *SwiftMailer*) отправить письмо через `smtp.yandex.ru`, но соединение обрывается по таймауту.
Стандартный таймаут 30 секунд, пробовал увеличивать до 60 - не помогло, да и не особо на это рассчитывал. В конфиге указано, что нужно подключаться по `tls`.

Все реквизиты указаны корректно и с хоста письма отправляются (правда, средствами [Foundation for Emails](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html), Swift не тестировал).
По `telnet` из контейнера к почтовому серверу на нужный порт тоже удаётся подключиться, а вот письма не отправляются.

Куда смотреть и как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно дело не в таймауте, т.к. за 30 секунд можно законнектится даже на диалапе. Скорее всего вы указали неправильный smtp порт. При использовании tls для smtp.yandex.ru нужно указывать 587 порт.